# How to make game wait before strats?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do when i run the game it wait 3s before it starts in Unity.
I put all gameobjetc in a empty object with code:

```
[SerializeField]
private float seconds = 3f;
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Wait());
}
private IEnumerator Wait()
{
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
}
```

And when I start the game its just frozen nothing is counting down.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `WaitForSeconds` corresponds to the time in the game and follows `Time.scale`, So when you set `Time.Scale` to `0`, no time passes. Use **`WaitForSecondsRealtime`** to resolve this issue, This method works independently of `Time.Scale`, and if you use Slow-Motion or Freeze effects in your game, consider this one:

```cs
yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve your issue by removing the `Time.timeScale = 0f;` code. Let me explain why.

If you decrease the timescale to say 0.5, you are increasing your time by two. So your `3 / 0.5 = 6 seconds`.
When you are setting your timescale to 0 you are essentially pausing your app because you are making your app wait infinitely.

So if you remove the timeScales like this it should work fine:

```
private IEnumerator Wait()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
}
```